# Need to pass additional parameter to event handler while using DownloadDataCompleted method

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I need to implement asynchronous downloading by using [WebClient.DownloadDataAsync Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144190(v=vs.110).aspx)

I've defined event handler as following:

```
 Private Sub DownloadCompleted(sender As Object, e As DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim bytes() As Byte = e.Result
        'do somthing with result
    End Sub
```

But I need to pass to this event handler an additional parameter together with downloaded result , value with which I created URI. For example:

`Dim pictureURI = "http://images.server.sample.com/" + myUniqueUserIdentifier`

I need to get `myUniqueUserIdentifier` on callback in `DownloadCompleted` sub.

I'm registering my event handler by using the following code:

`AddHandler webClient.DownloadDataCompleted, AddressOf DownloadCompleted`

I've only one guess, to extend `WebClient` object and to override `DownloadDataCompleted` object. But before I'm going to perform this I'd like to check is there more simpler solution?

Thank you.

Comment: please fix the title to something meaningful and related to the question and which will help future visitors...and we dont need tags in the title

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it already...

Comment: @Anatoly: Can you attache it to `sender`?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, I don't know. I came from Java world and only occasionally touching vb.net when need to fix some legacy code. I'm looking for any direction where should I move or simple example how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @Anatoly : Please look at [Add Custom Event to a Class in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229122/Add-Custom-Event-To-A-Class-in-VB-Net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`WebClient.DownloadDataAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144191(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which takes an additional object, and then recieve it again via the [`AsyncCompletedEventArgs.UserState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.userstate(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Here's an example:

```
Sub Main
    Dim url = "http://google.com"
    Dim client = new WebClient()
    AddHandler client.DownloadDataCompleted, AddressOf DownloadDataCompleted
    client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url), url) ' <- pass url as additional information...'
End Sub

Sub DownloadDataCompleted(sender as object, e as DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim raw as byte() = e.Result
    ' ... and recieve it in the event handler via the UserState property'
    Console.WriteLine(raw.Length & " bytes received from " & e.UserState.ToString())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to pass the parameter instead of AddressOf

```
AddHandler webClient.DownloadDataCompleted, Function(sender, e) DownloadCompleted(param)
```